# Salesforce api.status.salesforce.com returns no data

Tags: rest-api, search, custom-domain, mydomain

I have registered a custom domain (My Domain) in my Enterprise Edition Org and I am able to successfully login through the custom domain url.

Custom Domain: **mobilecustomdomain**

URL: https://mobilecustomdomain.my.salesforce.com

However, if I try to fetch details about the custom domain using salesforce provisioned apis, there is no data that is getting returned for the same. I have done dnslookup for the same and able to get the CNAME records.

API I have used
`GET https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/search/mobilecustomdomain`
Response:
`[]`

I have created this custom domain 2 days back.

Let me know what is the issue with the api here.

Thanks,
Saiteja

Comment: I got a 200 status OK response trying this.

Comment: 200 OK is returned irrespective of the result. 

https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/search/jayantdas (used your name, just kidding)

This as well returns 200, but no data.

Comment: Haha. Didn't know that. I first tried my custom domain, and then yours and thought it works.

Comment: Thats ok. I read somewhere that this doesn't support developer editions where custom domains are named <foo>.dev-ed.my.salesforce.com. Wondering why its not working for mine which is enterprise edition

Answer (score 1):

api.status.salesforce.com deals with instances of Salesforce itself rather than individual orgs such as yours. Example: https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instances/na14/status will tell you what's running on NA14 instance

You want https://mobilecustomdomain.my.salesforce.com/services/data/... See [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_getting_info_about_my_org.htm) for more info.

Comment: I think this is a way to go at this problem. Thank you ! I dont have 15+ reputation to upvote this. If you can upvote this question, I might reach the target to upvote yours :D